# Apache SSL Config With NodeJS Proxy Pass Fails to Start

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, ssl

I am trying to do a proxy pass in Apache on Ubuntu 16.04 to a nodejs service running in PM2.

I originally tried to use the service as a plain http service running over port 80, and that worked just fine.

Then I wanted to deploy it to production so it obviously needed to have an SSL cert on it. So I added in the first VirtualHost to redirect to the secured service and I added the SSL stuff to the original config to get it to run over port 443 with the current cert.

Currently I have a wildcard cert that will work with everything under domain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://my.domain.com/servicename
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName my.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/servicename


    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.key
    # I don't actually have a ca certificate so I tried adding the my.crt again with no luck. I also don't have any .pem files either
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <Location /servicename>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

However, when i save this configuration and do sudo systemctl restart apache2 it tells me that apache failed to start

```
 Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I run the systemctl status apache2.service and I get the following:

```
 apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
 Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
 apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-11-06 12:41:54 CST; 40s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 10361 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited,status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 9310 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 10476 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What am I doing wrong in the config?

Comment: Try `apachectl configtest` - that should report specific errors with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apachectl configtest` at the suggestion of @Kryten I was able to figure out that I did not have ssl installed so the solutions was to do `sudo a2enmod ssl` and apache started!